# Django validation questions

Tags: django, validation

1. For Django validation, I've seen a lot of people suggest putting it in the model  layer, which makes sense to me (to keep business logic consistent and in one place). However, I saw 2 ways of doing this: by writing a custom clean() method for every model, which can validate and clean the data, or by defining validators on model fields (called when the ModelForm cleans). Can someone more familiar with Django please discuss the pros and cons of each of these approaches?
2. I wrote a sample code, where my Model has a field zip_code, which has a validator (makes sure the zip code is exactly 5 numeric digits). If it's not, the validator raises a ValidationError.

In my view that adds this model, I have a try block looking for this ValidationError, to pass an appropriate error message to the template.

However, when submitting a 4 digit zip code, a ValueError is thrown instead, and displayed in the browser. It does say validation failed, so I am guessing the validator is kicking in, but I must be missing something in how the error is handled.

3. If a validation error is caught in the view, how should I come back to the form? Right now, i am doing something like

except ValidationError as e:
     render("template.html", {'form': original_form, 'error_message': str(e))

Thinking that this will render the original form with the previous input and the validation error message. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Did you meant return render(....)?

Comment: Yes, sorry I do have return render("template.html" ...